# DateTime Parameters in stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I have a stored procedure insert into to the table in SQL Server:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ThemHocSinh
    @TenHS NVARCHAR(255),
    @NgaySinh DATETIME,
    @TenChaMe NVARCHAR(255),
    @SDTChaMe VARCHAR(16),
    @DiaChi NVARCHAR(255),
    @LopHC VARCHAR(6)
AS
    INSERT INTO dbo.HocSinh (MaHS, TenHS, NgaySinh, NgayNhapHoc, TenChaMe, SDTChaMe, DiaChi, LopHC)
    VALUES (DEFAULT, @TenHS, @NgaySinh, DEFAULT, @TenChaMe, @SDTChaMe, @DiaChi, @LopHC)
```

I write a function in C# with Dapper and passing the dynamic parameters with `DateTime` type.

```
public void ThemHocSinh(string TenHS, DateTime NgaySinh, string TenChaMe, string SDT, string DiaChi, string LopHC)
{
    using (MamNonBK context = new MamNonBK())
    {
        using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString))
        {
            var p = new DynamicParameters(); 
            p.Add("@TenHS", TenHS);
            p.Add("@NgaySinh", NgaySinh); 
            p.Add("@TenChaMe", TenChaMe); 
            p.Add("@SDTChaMe", SDT); 
            p.Add("@DiaChi", DiaChi);
            p.Add("@LopHC", LopHC);

            db.Execute("ThemHocSinh", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        }
    }
}
```

But it seems my program crashes because the dateTime parameter does not match. My system date and time is formatted "dd/MM/yyyy". This is error when I call the function and pass a DateTime parameter.

> > **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:** The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. The statement has been terminated.

[image]

Comment: I would guess that the culture on the machine has a different formatting for dates

Comment: Which parameter is throwing? Given the error message, I'm assuming it's not `@NgaySinh`, but rather `@SDTChaMe`. Is that a date in the actual table? If so, I suggest fixing the types in the SP and code to match, or at least format it to the proper format before sending it to the procedure.

Comment: Why not use `Parameters.Add` and *tell* C# what type of parameter it is, so that it passed a `datetime`, and not an `nvarchar` that needs to be implicitly cast to one by the RDBMS?

Comment: The answer you have selected is not correct. Please show us the `CREATE TABLE` script for `HocSinh`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since SQL receives a string not formatted the way it wants, you can also use:

```
p.Add("@NgaySinh", NgaySinh.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

instead of:

```
p.Add("@NgaySinh", NgaySinh);
```

and I'm sure it'll work!

Comment: I trying this but still erorr. [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.imgur.com/DpbtuaE.jpg

Comment: Do not use this solution. This will not _always_ work (e.g. if dateformat is set to YDM). You should not pass a date to the server as a string - you should pass it as a date.